# Citation and Referencing in latex

Tags: biblatex

I have a question about referencing and citation in latex. The style I want to achieve is (in **bold**):

> This work is done by **Jiang and Su [JS09]**, where they....etc

In references:

> **[JS09]** Lingxiao Jiang and Zhendong Su. Automatic mining of
>   functionally equivalent code fragments via random testing. In
>   Proceedings of the Eighteenth International Sympo- sium on Software
>   Testing and Analysis, ISSTA '09, pages 81{92, New York, NY, USA,
>   2009. ACM.

I know for [JS09] you need to use Alpha style but don't know how to do the other part the author names. I tried nitbib but no luck.

I am working on sharelatex.

Comment: If you are really using `biblatex`, you could use `\textcite` and `style=alphabetic`.

Comment: @moewe thank you, this is what I am looking for. I had to set maxcitenames=2 to replace with et al when there are more than 2 authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `biblatex` with the [`alphabetic` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/40-style-alphabetic-biber.pdf) (`style=alphabetic`), you are looking for `\textcite`

```
\textcite{sigfridsson}
```